Estimating errors on mass spec intensities
I am writing residual gas analysis-quadrupole mass spectrometry (RGA-QMS) data reduction software in Python. I am trying to estimate errors on measured beam heights/intensities and could use a hand as my errors are just plain too low.
Our measurements consist of measured MID intensities $y'$ in amperes as a function of time $t$. We fit the baseline-corrected intensities $y$ as a function of time $t$ back to $t=0$ to determine the gas intensity that we would have measured if the gases hadn't needed time to equilibrate in the vacuum chamber. This is referred to as the 'fitted intensity'. I want to calculate the errors on these intensities to improve the robustness of the fitting models.
Errors are currently estimated from three sources:

The standard error, or the system's repeatability. This is measured as the percent standard deviation of the peak intensities of $\geq7$ subsequent gas standards, corrected for depletion (our gas standards slowly deplete, as they come from a constant source, so we need to correct for this depletion effect).

The Gaussian error in the instrumental noise. We measure this by measuring the intensities at 5 - 5.5 amu, where no gaseous species exist.

The Poisson-based error of the ion counting statistics.


EDIT: THE BELOW HAS BEEN EDITED TO INCLUDE $y_\text{stray}$
$\newcommand{\ystray}{y_\text{stray}}$
$\newcommand{\ytrue}{y_\text{true}}$
$\newcommand{\tdwell}{t_\text{dwell}}$
Let's formalize these relationships: first, consider that each "raw" measurement $y'$ is a combination of the true intensity of counted ions $y_\text{true}$, un-desirable 'stray' ions $\ystray$ plus instrumental noise $\epsilon$:
$$y' = \ytrue + \ystray + \epsilon$$
in which $y_\text{true}$ and $\ystray$ are Poisson distributed and therefore $\geq 0$, however, $\epsilon$ may cause small values of $y'$ or $b$ to be negative.
Because we lack independent measurements of $\ystray$ and $\epsilon$, we must infer both from the baseline measurements $b$. We therefore approximate that:

Noise is normally distributed around 0 with error $\sigma_b$:

$$\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_b)$$

$\ystray$ is the mean baseline intensity $\bar{b}$ with errors given by Poisson statistics.

Poisson counting errors are estimated by converting measured intensities to the number of electrons hitting the detector $n_e$ using the elemental charge $q$:
$$n_e = \frac{y_\text{true}t_\text{dwell}}{q}$$
where $t_\text{dwell}$ is the dwell time over the measurement. The error in the number of counted electrons is therefore:
$$\varepsilon_{n_e} = \sqrt{n_e} = \sqrt{\frac{y_\text{true}t_\text{dwell}}{q}}$$
such that the error $\varepsilon$ in $y_\text{true}$ is:
$$\varepsilon_{y_\text{true}} = \frac{q\sqrt{n_e}}{t_\text{dwell}}$$
$\varepsilon_{\ystray}$ is calculated identically.
When $y' \gg b$, we assume that $y_\text{true}$ is the baseline-corrected value $y$:
$$y = y' - \bar{b}$$
and when $y' \approx b$ or $y' < 0$, we use Bayesian techniques to estimate $y_\text{true}$.
Notating the standard error (1) as $\varepsilon_{y'}$, we arrive at the total error in each measurement:
$$\varepsilon_y = \sqrt{\varepsilon^2_{y_\text{true}} +\varepsilon^2_{\ystray} + \sigma^2_b + \varepsilon_{y'}}$$
While these aren't the only sources of error in intensity measurements, I thought that surely these would be the most significant and therefore provide a very reasonable estimation of the errors.
I was wrong.
A little more information: we are measuring at 2 amu (hydrogen), 3 amu (HD + helium-3), 4 amu (helium-4), and 40 amu (argon-40). While the two helium species are the critical measurements, intensities at 40 amu are by far the best example of how vastly underestimated these errors are:

40 amu y: [8.79109037e-12 9.81047258e-12 9.16161008e-12 9.20899318e-12
 9.28723348e-12 9.18557998e-12 9.78028197e-12 9.12099708e-12
 9.10378668e-12 9.68520487e-12 9.38878427e-12 9.72379448e-12]
40 amu y_err: [3.10109691e-14 3.45722709e-14 3.23052456e-14 3.24707759e-14
 3.27441111e-14 3.23889828e-14 3.44667780e-14 3.21633688e-14
 3.21032470e-14 3.41345636e-14 3.30988949e-14 3.42694004e-14]


40 amu y: [8.85106265e-12 8.96876345e-12 9.63826295e-12 9.70694215e-12
 9.56583135e-12 9.67781935e-12 9.51369055e-12 1.00306014e-11
 9.49207605e-12 1.02375318e-11 9.76851875e-12 9.69370965e-12]
40 amu y_err: [3.11851759e-14 3.15967683e-14 3.39381329e-14 3.41783315e-14
 3.36848135e-14 3.40764772e-14 3.35024601e-14 3.53103296e-14
 3.34268676e-14 3.60340954e-14 3.43936916e-14 3.41320520e-14]

While not as bad, we can also see how underestimated the errors are at 4 amu as well:

4 amu y: [8.1676155e-13 8.0311035e-13 8.0506375e-13 8.0545125e-13 8.0100485e-13
 8.2227135e-13 8.0774045e-13 8.2361055e-13 8.3711635e-13 8.0967975e-13
 8.2801175e-13 8.2636875e-13]
4 amu y_err: [3.86149103e-15 3.82625487e-15 3.83128028e-15 3.83227785e-15
 3.82084446e-15 3.87578890e-15 3.83817558e-15 3.87927063e-15
 3.91452441e-15 3.84317784e-15 3.89073095e-15 3.88644954e-15]

I am therefore hoping for

explanations as to why the estimated errors fail to account for the full scatter in the measurements
ideas on including other sources of errors
any refinements of the current approach

For example, I wonder about using ion counting statistics with the measured intensities directly: this is because our system uses a secondary electron multiplier (SEM), greatly amplifying the number of electrons per counted ion. I have no idea how to 'correct' for this effect based on SEM voltage, or whether I should.
Any ideas, pointers, suggestions, etc. would be greatly appreciated!

Off the cuff, as some mentioned a photomultiplier would lead to a highly nonlinear (power law?) response and you might be seeing that in the plots in your other question, for instance at 40 amu amplitudes are orders of magnitude smaller yet the normalized profile of the time-dependence is comparable to that at 2 amu. Or are amplitudes somehow automatically scaled by some unreported factor? Work with log-transformed data? // Your analysis is quite sophisticated but you don't explain the relative magnitude of the error sources here, which makes it harder to provide feedback.

This kind of noise source analysis is useful in that it might ultimately help you reduce those sources, but if you can't then there isn't much use in computing the sources, or is there (other than to understand what's happening in your experiment)? What advantage over simply measuring the scatter and fitting it to estimate uncertainties?

The error of the standards $\epsilon_{y'}$, that is based on experimentally observed variations and seems to me like it already incorporates the other errors. So simply using the sum $$\varepsilon_y^2 = {\varepsilon^2_{y_\text{true}} + \sigma^2_b + \varepsilon_{y'}}$$ seems not correct. The nature of the measurements for deriving this error $\epsilon_{y'}$ must be more precisely described in order to derive a $\varepsilon_y$ from it.

$\varepsilon_{y'}$ is only intended to measure the system's ability to repeat the same measurement. We use an un-weighted calculation to determine the repeatability, so this should not include other errors. I'm not sure I agree that this should capture things like ion counting errors or the baseline correction error. I am open to the idea that I am wrong, though.

Potential ways to get different standard deviations
You are computing error bars based on
$$n_e = \frac{y_\text{true}t_\text{dwell}}{q}$$
there are at least two possible errors that can make you over estimate the underlying count numbers and underestimate the standard deviation in the signal.

It might be that you are using an electron multiplier and the number of electrons is a multiple of the number of ions. The number of ions should be the basis for computing the noise.

It is possible that you are using wrong dwell times. You are making measurements every 5 seconds, but those 5 seconds are not the dwell times. The spectrometer scans multiple channels and only spends a fraction of the 5 seconds on measuring a particular mass.
(This might be stating something that you might already know, but it is possible that you missed this)


Possibly the standard deviations are fine
Another aspect is that your linear model might be incorrect.
You assume that the lack in goodness of fit is due to miscalculations of the standard deviations, but it can also be that your underlying model is not a straight line.
Variations in the signal do not only happen due to randomness in the counting following a Poisson distribution. The rate parameter of that Poisson distribution might be fluctuating differently than you expect. For example, there might be instabilities in the pressures of your system or in the ioniser.
Your argon signal seems strong, you could try an experiment measuring the 40 amu with a higher frequency, e.g. shorter dwell times and without measuring other masses. You might see a signal with a strong autocorrelation that corresponds reasonably to the standard deviation of the Poisson noise. (ie. if on shorter time scales the Poisson rate fluctuates less, then you can expect neighbouring measurements to be closer to each other if the difference in time is smaller)
You might get for example output like:

would you distrust the ion count error bars, or would you distrust the signal being a straight line?

It is remarkable that the lower intensity signal has a smaller coefficient of varition. This is not what you would expect of the standard deviation is the square root of the expected value. This indicates that the first part, correcting the counts with a factor, is probably not the only thing. The second part of the answer is relevant as well, and you likely have a much different source of error then only the sampling variation in collecting counts. Unless the difference in signal does not relate to a difference in counts, and the 4 amu measurement has a longer dwell time than the 40 amu.

Thanks for your response! You are correct that we are using an electron multiplier and I am not sure how to convert from counted electrons to counted ions based on SEM voltage and ion source settings, so I am currently using the electron counts. We are using the correct dwell times per mass, not a single cycle-wide dwell time. As for the linear model, you're correct that the data do not obey a linear trend over time. In the past, we have simplified everything to a linear model, however, my program also offers logarithmic and exponential decay models as well to capture the full trends.

Actually, in the three examples provided, I would argue there is no trend and we should be averaging the intensities, however, the "Linear" model is just what I happened to be using at the time I took these screenshots.

I remember using ptr-ms and it had a way to determine exact ion counts by some similar formula that relates current with counts (but maybe with an additional muktiplier). The ion counts is what you want. The electron counts are just a multiple of the ion counts with only a small amount of randomness.

@ohshitgorillas are the dwell times the same for different masses? The signal at 4amu is smaller than the signal at 40amu, but the coefficient of variation is better. That is not typical of the noise is due to poisson statistics. It seems like there is something else that causes variations in the signal from argon ions.

No, the dwell times are 0.125 sec for 40 amu and ~4 seconds for 4 amu. We only measure argon as a bellwether to check the health of the vacuum system, hence the short dwell. We are mostly concerned with helium isotopes at 3 and 4 amu, so we dwell over those for much longer.

@ohshitgorillas that is interesting. So the signal for 4 amu can be seen as resulting into relatively 320 more counts (due to longer dwell times) and the roughly hundred times smaller signal actually represent a three times larger amount of counts. Then the difference in the coefficient of variation might be reasonable. Possibly you could similate this by making experiments with different concentrations. What you would expect is that $\frac{\epsilon_y}{y} \propto \sqrt{n_e}$ and of youbcan verify whether this holds then you are only ledt with determining the constant of proportionality.
